# Can I marry my brother's sister in law?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, mahram

I have heard in a lecture before that this is not allowed (2 brothers marrying to women who are sisters). Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

Quran 4:22-23 gives a list of women a man cannot marry.

**Quran 4:22-23**

> Do not marry the women whom your fathers married, although what is past is past. This indeed was a shameful deed, a hateful thing, and an evil way. (22) Forbidden to you are your mothers, your daughters, your sisters, your father's sisters and your mother's sisters, your brother's daughters and your sister's daughters, your milk-mothers, your milk-sisters, the mothers of your wives, and the stepdaughters - who are your foster-children, born of your wives with whom you have consummated the marriage; but if you have not consummated the marriage with them, there will be no blame upon you (if you marry their daughters). **It is also forbidden** for you to take the wives of the sons who have sprung from your loins and **to take two sisters together in marriage**, although what is past is past. Surely Allah is All-Forgiving, All-Compassionate.

The restriction is on single person marrying two sisters.

To the best of my knowledge there is no restriction on two brothers marrying two sisters.

Please note that you need to be careful. In such marriages, problem in one marriage can easily spill over to the other marriage.